# Spring security Session Timeout handling for Ajax calls redirect to login not working

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

There are a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730917/spring-security-session-timeout-handling-for-ajax-calls) similar to my question but not working. I am following [this blog](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/spring-security-part-vi-session-timeout-handling-for-ajax-calls/) to redirect ajax request to login page when session timeout but in my case it is not working. here is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableAnalyzer;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableCauseExtractor;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter extends GenericFilterBean{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.class);

    private ThrowableAnalyzer throwableAnalyzer = new DefaultThrowableAnalyzer();
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    private int customSessionExpiredErrorCode = 901;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        try
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            logger.debug("Chain processed normally");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Throwable[] causeChain = throwableAnalyzer.determineCauseChain(ex);
            RuntimeException ase = (AuthenticationException) throwableAnalyzer.getFirstThrowableOfType(AuthenticationException.class, causeChain);

            if (ase == null)
            {
                ase = (AccessDeniedException) throwableAnalyzer.getFirstThrowableOfType(AccessDeniedException.class, causeChain);
            }

            if (ase != null)
            {
                if (ase instanceof AuthenticationException)
                {
                    throw ase;
                }
                else if (ase instanceof AccessDeniedException)
                {

                    if (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()))
                    {
                        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;

                        logger.info("User session expired or not logged in yet");
                        String ajaxHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("X-Requested-With");

                        if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader))
                        {
                            logger.info("Ajax call detected, send {} error code", this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);


                            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/home/login");



                            return;
                        }else
                        {

                            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/home/login");
                            logger.info("Redirect to login page");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response,"/home/login");
                        return; 
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }



    private static final class DefaultThrowableAnalyzer extends ThrowableAnalyzer
    {
        /**
         * @see org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableAnalyzer#initExtractorMap()
         */
        protected void initExtractorMap()
        {
            super.initExtractorMap();

            registerExtractor(ServletException.class, new ThrowableCauseExtractor()
            {
                public Throwable extractCause(Throwable throwable)
                {
                    ThrowableAnalyzer.verifyThrowableHierarchy(throwable, ServletException.class);
                    return ((ServletException) throwable).getRootCause();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void setCustomSessionExpiredErrorCode(int customSessionExpiredErrorCode)
    {
        this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode = customSessionExpiredErrorCode;
    }
}
```

I have added this `<security:custom-filter ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>` and the ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter bean in the xml configuration file but not working. When i debug it goes to redirect code but the redirect is not redirecting to login.

Comment: For ajax call it will not redirect but it sends response with status code 302 to the browser. You have to read that status code from JavaScript or jquery and you have redirect from JS code using location.href="loginpage".

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.

Comment: Your AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter is not necessary in this scenario. As session is expired without this filter also you should get response with status code 302 or 401 you can handle this from your front end code.

Comment: can you elaborate on "Your AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter is not necessary in this scenario"?

Comment: If you want auto redirect functionality follow my answer in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57598264/2825798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ajax call response status after redirect will be 200 instead of 302. There is no option left to identify redirection from status.

Instead of changing status code by implementing your own filter (order before `ExceptionTranslationFilter`), breaking filter chain by re-throwing exception.

**Simple way is**
1. Add this hidden div in login page.

```html
<div style="display:none">LOGIN_PAGE_IDENTIFIER</div>
```

2. And in your each JSP page.(or, If you have any config.js which you include in every jsp page, add below code there)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if(xhr.responseText.indexOf("LOGIN_PAGE_IDENTIFIER") != -1)
            window.location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

**PS**:
About your concern regarding your AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter
If you are receiving 901 status in ajax response then

```html
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if(xhr.status == 901)
        window.location.reload();
});
```

adding this to your every JSP page should solve your problem.

Comment: @Yirga Let me know. Which one worked for you. Status code changing or adding hidden div in login page?

Comment: Also. Let me suggest you the very interesting way of achieving logout functionality which is auto logout if user is idle for say 10 minute in the browser it will automatically redirects to login page, that is also without any intervention of user. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57598264/2825798

Comment: i used the status code. I have another question. After what filter should we assign if we want to have a filter that runs before every controller method.

Comment: All filters runs before and after your controller method. ExceptionTranslationFilter is the last filter, we can add your AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter before or after exceptionTranslationFilter. If we add before we have to break the chain and ensure it not reached exceptionTranslationFilter. If we add after exceptionTranslationFilter then you should change the status.